# Bind Combobox form LIST<> in datagirdview

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

How can i bind the combobox with LIST<> in datagridview . For Binding the 'Combobox' 
Here i am directly assign the value in binding source .

```
 programEntityBindingSource.DataSource = _Usercom.GetProgramName();
```

How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run through the datagridview rows and bind it one by one as follows,

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridViewProducts.Rows) 
{
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell =DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells("myProductCol");
    cell.DataSource = _Usercom.GetProgramName();
    cell.DataPropertyName = "ProgramName";        
    cell.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cell.ValueMember = "Self"; // key to getting the databinding to work
    // no need to set cell.Value anymore!
}
```

Comment: What is IProduct here & Where i need to use this

Comment: that line is not required. check now.

Comment: Do you really need to loop, you can assign the `Datasource` to the column itself ! !